# how to enable tls 1.3 on macos ventura

Tags: c#, .net, macos, ssl, tls1.3

This is weird thing, I'm not able to run tls 1.3 under .net 6 while running same configuration for windows 11 that's works, the configuration is pretty simple:

```
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(k =>
{
    k.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
    {
        options.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13;
    });
});
```

On mac I'm receiving this issue from chrome: `err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch` and from postman: `Error: write EPROTO 140186045514584:error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 70`

I've also have tried to modify mac configuration with:

```
sudo defaults write  /Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkd tcp_connect_enable_tls13 1
```

But this didn't help me at all, does anyone faced with similar issue?

Comment: Played with the opensll installation on your Mac? The error references boringsll (a google fork of opensll). I doubt that this normal?

Comment: Yes, I guess. I already had assigned a certificate generated by dotnet itself. Same on windows 11 machine, but it works under the box wether for mac not, strange..